# Reading ambiguous column name in Spark sql Dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have duplicate columns in text file and when I try to load that text file using spark scala code, it gets loaded successfully into data frame and I can see the first 20 rows by df.Show()

Full Code:-

```
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val hivesql = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
 val rdd = sc.textFile("/...FilePath.../*")
 val fieldCount = rdd.map(_.split("[|]")).map(x => x.size).first()
 val field = rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2==0).map(_._1).first()
 val fields = field.split("[|]").map(fieldName =>StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable=true))
 val schema = StructType(fields)
 val rowRDD = rdd.map(_.split("[|]")).map(attributes => getARow(attributes,fieldCount))

val df = hivesql.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
df.registerTempTable("Sample_File")
df.Show()
```

Till this point my code works fine.
But as soon as I try below code then it gives me error.

```
val results = hivesql.sql("Select id,sequence,sequence from Sample_File")
```

so I have 2 columns with same name in text file i.e sequence
How can I access that two columns.. I tried with sequence#2 but still not working
Spark Version:-1.6.0
Scala Version:- 2.10.5

```
result of df.printschema()
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- sequence: string (nullable = true)
|-- sequence: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: can you update the `df.printSchema()` results over here? and can update the Question with full code you have tried?

Comment: updated with my sample code

Comment: could you share the sample line of input data?

Comment: id|sequence|sequence
1|657985|657985
2|689654|685485

Comment: updated the answer, please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second @smart_coder's approach,  I  have a slightly different approach though. Please find it below.

You need to have unique column names to do query from hivesql.sql.

you can rename the column names dynamically by using below code:

Your code:

```
val df = hivesql.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

After this point, we need to remove ambiguity, below is the solution:

```
var list = df.schema.map(_.name).toList

for(i <- 0 to list.size -1){
    val cont = list.count(_ == list(i))
    val col = list(i)
    
    if(cont != 1){
        list = list.take(i) ++ List(col+i) ++ list.drop(i+1)
    }
}

val df1 = df.toDF(list: _*)
```

// you would get the output as below:
result of df1.printschema()

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- sequence1: string (nullable = true)
|-- sequence: string (nullable = true)
```

So basically, we are getting all the column names as a list, then checking if any column is repeating more than once,
if a column is repeating, we are appending the column name with the index, then we create a new dataframe d1 with the new list with renamed column names.

I have tested this in Spark 2.4, but it should work in 1.6 as well.

Comment: if you want to rename in reverse order, you can do for(i <- list.size -1 to 0 by -1)

Comment: Thanks Rohit., Just tweak one line and it started working.. Previously it was showing schema as id, Sequence,............,Sequence12,..   So replaced below line "list = list.take(i) ++ List(col+cont) ++ list.drop(i+1)"

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you to resolve your problem. I have tested this in Spark 1.6.3.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hivesql = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val rdd = sc.textFile("/...FilePath.../*")
val fieldCount = rdd.map(_.split("[|]")).map(x => x.size).first()
val field = rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2==0).map(_._1).first()
val fields = field.split("[|]").map(fieldName =>StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable=true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
val rowRDD = rdd.map(_.split("[|]")).map(attributes => getARow(attributes,fieldCount))

val df = hivesql.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

val colNames = Seq("id","sequence1","sequence2")
val df1 = df.toDF(colNames: _*)

df1.registerTempTable("Sample_File")

val results = hivesql.sql("select id,sequence1,sequence2 from Sample_File")
```

Comment: I can't use fixed set of column names.. Because column may change in between quarter. For e.g. this quarter file may contain 3 columns and for next quarter may contain 10 columns (out of which 3 columns may be duplicate)

Comment: Please update the question so that can investigate.

Comment: What is your final schema is that hive or??